# 'FLAG_FULLSCREEN: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java what is the alternative?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

what is the alternative for this code?

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
)
```

'FLAG_FULLSCREEN: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java